# Imagemagick Add Border to Inner Rectangle Only

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to add a border to the 100x100 blue square only, without adding it to the 200x200 background red frame. How would I achieve this? I've experimented with many configurations including parentheses ().

`exec("convert -size 200x200 xc:red -size 100x100 -draw rectangle -bordercolor yellow -border 2 xc:blue -geometry +5+5 -composite temp_bg.png ")`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting with the blue box, adding a border and then extending like this:

```
magick -size 100x100 xc:blue -bordercolor lime -border 10 -gravity northwest -background red -extent 400x400 -bordercolor yellow -border 10 result.png
```

[image]

Sorry, no time, gotta dash - add in a `-page ...` or `-geometry ...` before `extent` to set the position of the blue box.

Comment: Hi Mark - thats not working for me? Here is what I did in PHP (where {$convert} is local path to convert). `exec("{$convert} -size 100x100 xc:blue -bordercolor lime -border 10 -gravity northwest -background red -extent 400x400 -bordercolor yellow -border 10 result.png")` No go

Comment: Please be more specific about *"No go"*. Did it crash? Did you get an error? If so, what error? What was the result?

Comment: Sorry just doesn't render the image at all

Comment: My apologies. I had a typo. That did work! Thank you!!